# Post image with jQuery to Spring java as MultipartFile

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

I'm trying to send image to my server to store it to mysql database.

I'm trying to post Formdata with jQuery and receive it like a java MultipartFile and convert it to bytes[]. I found a few ways to do it , but neither is working, 
can somebody help me please?

This is my best try:

```
<form>
<input type="file" id="file"/>
<a onclick="uploadImage()"  >Upload</a>
</form>
```

JS

```
function uploadImage() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '/admin/uploadImage',
        headers : {
            "X-CSRF-TOKEN" : token
        },
        data : formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    }); 
    alert("proso");
}
```

and JAVA

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void save(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
    {

        try
        {

            File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
            convFile.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("file: " + convFile.getTotalSpace());
            byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) convFile.length()];

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(convFile);
            fileInputStream.read(bFile);
            fileInputStream.close();
            Files newFile = new Files();
            newFile.setFileName("4h");
            newFile.setData(bFile);
            filesRepository.save(newFile);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void save(MultipartHttpServletRequest request)
{

    try
    {
        Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            MultipartFile file = request.getFile(itr.next());

            if(file != null) {
                File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
                convFile.createNewFile();
               System.out.println("file: " + convFile.getTotalSpace());
               byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) convFile.length()];

               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new 
               FileInputStream(convFile);
               fileInputStream.read(bFile);
               fileInputStream.close();
               Files newFile = new Files();
               newFile.setFileName("4h");
               newFile.setData(bFile);
               filesRepository.save(newFile);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There is a lot lot simpler way, because File have a getBytes() function and i did'nt find one example with it, but it works just fine.